# Most efficient way to structure and retrieve data for two player turn based game using Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to know if the following structure I'm using for storing data and then retrieving it is efficient, or if there is a better way. My code does appear to work, but I'm worried in case more data is being transferred/processed than needs to be.

This is a two player, turn based game.  Player 1 sends his move to the realtime database, and player 2 retrieves it.  It's important that he retrieves the moves in the correct order (ie. the same order they were sent by player 1).

This is the code I'm using to send the players' moves to the database:

```
multiplayer.sendMove = function(roomRef, turnNum, vectorX, vectorY){

    var currentMove = {

                n: turnNum,
                x: vectorX,
                y: vectorY            
    };

    var moveRef = roomRef.child("moves").push();

    moveRef.set(currentMove, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error sending move.", error);    
        } else { 
            console.log("move sent");    
        }
    })

}
```

This creates the following sort of entry in the database:

```
{
  "rooms": {
    "-LXU8-36ISMY8YZnI7fr": {
      "moves": {
        "-LXZv-7zMCZdrH7ffoWf": {"n": 1, "x": 532, "y": 242},
        "-LXZv7LlQTkBEtls0PP2": {"n": 2, "x": 352, "y": 944}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, I am retrieving the move corresponding to the current turn using the following:

```
function listenForOpponentMove(roomRef, turnNum){

  var moveRef = roomRef.child('moves').orderByChild("n").equalTo(turnNum);

  moveRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot){

    if(snapshot.val()){

      var move = snapshot.val();
      console.log("move received: x = " + move.x + ", y = " + move.y);
    }
  })
}
```

My particular concern is that as the number of turns in one game increases, and assuming I will eventually want to store more data for each move than just an x and y value, that when I do a search in the 'moves' node for the current turn, it will be looking through quite a lot of data. What I'm not clear about is whether ALL the data in the 'moves' node is going to get transferred to the client each time a child is added, or only the current move that matches the turn I'm searching for by using 'orderByChild'.

Many thanks.

Comment: You started off with a very broad question ("What's the most efficient...") but ended with a very specific issue ("What I'm not clear about...").  Are you just looking to have this specific concern addressed?

Comment: My first concern is whether my code is efficient. I'd like someone to point out if there are any issues with the way I'm going about storing and retrieving data, that might cause an unnecessary amount of data transfer, especially as the number of moves increases, and the amount of data stored within each move increases.  The specific question I asked at the end (does all the data in the moves node get transferred or processed when querying the database using my current code) is secondary, but I feel if I understood what is happening there, it might help me to answer my primary concern. Thanks